# Java: JPA Spring Inverse OneToOne Relationships

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa

Is there a possible way to do a reverse relationship with JPA and Spring with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check https://kaiso.github.io/relmongo/ Looks promising for me.
It is based on Spring data mongodb and provides aka-JPA annotations.
However if you need relationships I would not use MongoDB :)